# MAUI - loading data

Tags: database, user-interface, maui

My question is very easy. What is the correct point for loading data from service/database in the page or view?

I am using `OnAppearing` method:

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
            base.OnAppearing();

            _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                    await Task.Delay(500);
                    await LoadData();
            });
}
private async Task LoadData()
{
            this.Items = await this.LoadDataFromDatabase();
}
```

Definition of items:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<Product>? _items = null;
```

The database returns a maximum of 20 items.

I use `ScrollView` with `HorizontalWrapLayout` and `DataTemplate` for items.

DataTemplate:

- Border
- -- Grid with rows
- --- Label
- --- Label
- --- Label

My problem is that the application is not smooth. Flyout menu is not smooth. It seems like UI wait for loading data. Loading data from database takes +/- 100ms however displaying data (20 items) on the page takes another 3-4sec. User experience is not very smooth in Release mode. The same result is also in Mobile/Tablet/Virtual devices/Phyical devices.

I also measured the speed of HorizontalWrapLayout:

- Measure: ~10ms
- ArrangeChildren: ~15ms

I have many of these logos in android:

Skipped 363 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

What can be wrong? Is it possible that this is MAUI problem? I load the data and the whole display happens automatically via bindable property = Items. What is the correct point of loading data (Constructor in model or OnAppearing or.... )?

- I uses Net7.0 and last version of MAUI => 7.0.52
- Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5 Preview 2
- Android API 33, Android v13 (virtual devices also phyzical devices)
- PC: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10850K CPU @ 3.60GHz, 32 GB ram

I am providing more information because my assumption is that the problem is not in weak devices.

Thank you for any advice, recommendations, suggestions, etc.

**Edit 1:**

Now I noticed a very interesting thing. HorizontalWrapLayoutManager is very fast (I listed the times above). However, Measure and ArrangeChildren are called 128-time to display data. (~10ms + ~15ms) * 128 = 3200ms. A very interesting thing is that the widthConstraint parameter for Manager is always the same, but the heightConstraint changes alternately between 1493 and Infinity. Is there any logic why the manager is called 128 times when displaying 8 items?

**Edit 2:**

I reduced my xaml step by step. After removing each parent view, the recalculation of the Manager is called less times. By removing almost everything, recalculation in the manager is called only 4 times. It also seems that if there is a parent Grid element with Auto size for Column or Row, the number of recalculations increases. I understand the logic of the recalculation, but it causes the display of data to be very slow in the final. Accordint to my logs, methods (Measure and Arrange) on the View inside the Manager cause a final delay when called repeatedly. Would not the solution be to save the data and call these methods only once?

Comment: drawing 20 items on the page should not take 4s.   Without seeing more of the relevant code it's impossible to say what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out that I see this:

```
await Task.Delay(500);
```

In a question related to performance and speed.

I do not know what you plan to do with this, and why you are doing it. But whatever the reason, please remove that line.

Second, if you are using Android, please make sure you test your performance in release. It may differ in order of magnitudes compared to the performance you see in debug.

If this does not help, try CollectionView, or DataGrid, and see if it will get better.

Edit: Just want to add, you are doing it correctly. I often use OnAppearing for loading and displaying data. (as command in my ViewModels)

Comment: Hello, for explanation, Delay(500) is for improving user experience. The flyout menu without this delay only cuts. The flyout menu with this delay can be closed more smoothly even when a partial cut occurs. It seems that the MainThread does not manage the animation for the Flayout menu + loading a new page + displaying the data after I set them in Items in another task. I am assuming that the binding is again switched to MainThread after setting Items. I am not sure if this is a problem with my data loading, or a MAUI problem, or a problem on the Android side.

Comment: @Jozef ok, lets drop this delay for a second. How is your performance if you deploy release version on the device?

Comment: A higher delay does not change the smoothness of the flyout menu. The animation is smooth up to 50% and then it cuts out. However, a higher delay slightly improves the impression of displaying the page and subsequently of loading data. It is obvious that the MainThread has time to render the page and then it is busy for displaying the data. With a low delay, instead of the page, only a white screen is displayed for a while, and then the entire page with data. It seems that my problem or slowdown is caused by what happens in MAUI after setting Items. *** I describe the behavior in the release.

Comment: @Jozef 4 sec is too much. Unrealistic for any amount of drawing.

Comment: Hello, I have added new findings to the previous post

Comment: @Jozef may I see the xaml file. Your problem is very interesting, and I want to reproduce it so I can delve into it as well.

Comment: Hello, I reduced my xaml step by step. After removing each parent view, the recalculation of the Manager is called less times. By removing almost everything, recalculation in the manager is called only 4 times. It also seems that if there is a parent Grid element with Auto size for Column or Row, the number of recalculations increases. I understand the logic of the recalculation, but it causes the display of data to be very slow in the final. Accordint to my logs, methods (Measure and Arrange) on the View inside the Manager cause a final delay when called repeatedly.

Comment: Would not the solution be to save the data and call these methods only once?

Comment: @Jozef I really cant say for sure. I have to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: I implemented cache for HorizontalWrapLayoutManager and finally it works as expected. Application is fast and data is displayed inmediately. It was a struggle, but only thanks to your questions, I thought of doing more new tests, comparisons and, in the final case, finding a solution. Thank you very much for your willingness and help.

Answer (score 0):

My summarization:

I use HorizontalWrapLayout with custom implementation for HorizontalWrapLayoutManager.

I foud out that Manarger is very fast, however ArrangeChildren and Measure are called more times. The number depends on the number of parents and the layout of the screen. The number of calls also affects the auto size in parent's Grids. Repeated recalculation and calls to Measure/ArrangeChildren in HorizontalWrapLayoutManager cause a large delay when displaying data in HorizontalWrapLayout.

I solved the problem by updating the HorizontalWrapLayoutManager. Manager stores the data returned from Measure and Arrange for each child. The first call will be recalculated. In the event that the items, padding, spacing, widthConstraint or other essential values have not changed during subsequent calls, the Manager no longer calls Measure and Arrange for each view, but returns data from the cache.

Small test:

- HorizontalWrapLayoutManager without cache = 128 calls => ~3100ms
- HorizontalWrapLayoutManager with cache = 128 calls => **~100ms**

So far, I have not found any problems that would result from the cache. In the future, however, it is not excluded that recalculation will have to occur when other properties of HorizontalWrapLayout are changed.